# How to access $scope variables on AngularJS from Controller to view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angular-ng-if

I have a simple scope variable on my AngularJS Controller. I have assigned it a specific endpoint value like so:

```
$scope.isItAvailable = endpoint.IS_IT_AVAILABLE;
```

How do I assign it in my view(HTML) in order to have an ng-if say, if it it true show it, if it is false hide it.

I have tried it implementing a function, have a `ctrl.checkIfavailable`, and calling it in the HTML, but nothing is helping. The value is never been read on the view side.

**Something like this**:

```
  $scope.checkIfItIsAvailable = () => {
    return $scope.isZKAvailable
  }
```

And called that in the `ng-if`. Tried as a controller as well, but didn't work.

I consoled.log the response from the server and I get a boolean value`true or false`, depending on the situation

Here is my code for the HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-8" ng-if="Ctrl.isItAvailable">
.... // More code here
</div>
```

And in the controller:

```
  $scope.isItAvailable = endpoint.IS_IT_AVAILABLE;

  console.log(endpoints.IS_IT_AVAILABLE); // This returns the boolean value I 
  // want to access
```

**Current Result**
Now, if I leave the ng-if, like that, I don't see the element as it doesn't access it at all.

**Expected Results**
I want to show/hide the element, depending on the value of isItAvailable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you attached it to the `$scope`, just use it like this

```
<div class="col-lg-8" ng-if="isItAvailable">

</div>
```

If you want to use the ControllerAs syntax, define the `isItAvailable` to `this` instead of `$scope` in the controller and then name the `ng-controller="yourControllerName as Ctrl"` in the view. You then refere to the `isItAvailable` as `Ctrl.isItAvailable`